# Create a plugin with new shortcodes derived from WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, shortcode

WooCommerce comes with standard shortcode [product_category]. 
I wanted to get a shortcode with the same behavior, but filtering per vendor (a custom taxonomy) instead of per category.
So I have replicated and modified the code of [product_category], directly in woocommerce file class-wc-shortcodes.php to create [product_vendor].

This way, it is working fine. But I know it is not proper because my shortcodes will be erased at each upgrade.

So I tried to create my own plugin to host the code of [product_vendor]. 
But simply moving the code into it, is not working (my website gets down). I also tried to declare global $woocommerce at the begining. Not working either. I guess it is because the code is refering to elements of class WC_Shortcodes and woocommerce functions... but I am not at ease with class so I don't know how to solve the issue...!

Here is the code I wrote in class-wc-shortcodes.php. Could you tell me what are the changes I should do so that this code is working in my own plugin ?

Many thanks

```
class WC_Shortcodes {

/**
 * Init shortcodes.
 */
public static function init() {
    $shortcodes = array(
        'product'                    => __CLASS__ . '::product',
        'product_page'               => __CLASS__ . '::product_page',
        'product_category'           => __CLASS__ . '::product_category',
        'product_vendor'             => __CLASS__ . '::product_vendor',  //new shortcode

...
 }
```

(...)

```
/**
 * Shortcode : List of products per vendor.
 */
public static function product_vendor( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'per_page' => '12',
        'columns'  => '4',
        'orderby'  => 'category',
        'order'    => 'asc',
        'vendor' => '',  // Slugs
        'operator' => 'IN'
    ), $atts, 'product_vendor' );

    if ( ! $atts['vendor'] ) {
        return ''; 
    }

    // Default ordering args
    $ordering_args = WC()->query->get_catalog_ordering_args( $atts['orderby'], $atts['order'] );
    $meta_query    = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
    $query_args    = array( 
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'orderby'             => $ordering_args['orderby'],
        'order'               => $ordering_args['order'],
        'posts_per_page'      => $atts['per_page'],
        'meta_query'          => $meta_query
    );

    $query_args = self::_maybe_add_vendor_args( $query_args, $atts['vendor'], $atts['operator'] );

    if ( isset( $ordering_args['meta_key'] ) ) {
        $query_args['meta_key'] = $ordering_args['meta_key'];
    }

    $return = self::product_loop( $query_args, $atts, 'product_cat' );

    // Remove ordering query arguments
    WC()->query->remove_ordering_args();

    return $return;
}
```

(...)

```
    private static function _maybe_add_vendor_args( $args, $vendor, $operator ) {
    if ( ! empty( $vendor ) ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'yith_shop_vendor',
                'terms'    => array_map( 'sanitize_title', explode( ',', $vendor ) ),
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'operator' => $operator
            )
        );
    }

    return $args;
}
```

In my own plugin, I have "copy paste" the code, with minor changes. But if I activate this plugin, my site can't be launched at all. I also tried to include my function in "class WC_Shortcodes", or to add/remove the declaration of global variable $woocommerce... Here is what I wrote in my plugin :

```
function test_shortcode_in_my_plugin ($atts){
global $woocommerce;
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'per_page' => '12',
        'columns'  => '4',
        'orderby'  => 'category',
        'order'    => 'asc',
        'vendor' => '',  // Slugs
        'operator' => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
    ), $atts, 'product_vendor' );

    if ( ! $atts['vendor'] ) {
        return ''; //si aucune catégorie n'est spécifiée, ne rien retourner
    }

    // Default ordering args
    $ordering_args = WC()->query->get_catalog_ordering_args( $atts['orderby'], $atts['order'] );
    $meta_query    = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
    $query_args    = array( // construction du tableau de résultats
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'orderby'             => $ordering_args['orderby'],
        'order'               => $ordering_args['order'],
        'posts_per_page'      => $atts['per_page'],
        'meta_query'          => $meta_query
    );

    $query_args = self::_maybe_add_vendor_args( $query_args, $atts['vendor'], $atts['operator'] );
    // Fonction qui ajoute la condition sur le "vendor" dans la requete

    if ( isset( $ordering_args['meta_key'] ) ) {
        $query_args['meta_key'] = $ordering_args['meta_key'];
    }

    $return = self::product_loop( $query_args, $atts, 'product_cat' );

    // Remove ordering query arguments
    WC()->query->remove_ordering_args();

    return $return;
}

add_shortcode( 'test_shortcode', 'test_shortcode_in_my_plugin' );
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is stopping you from writing your own plugin and adding these methods there?

Comment: I tried to create my own plugin, but "copy paste" the code does not work (I can't even launch my site when I activate the plugin). I will add the code I wrote in my main message.

Comment: If your site won't launch when you activate the plugin then you need to take steps to debug your plugin. You could have something as simple as a type. Try enabling `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and take a look at the resulting error logs.